# multiple statements found while compiling a single statement У меня выводит ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import nltk

text = "Сонце гріє ще майже по-літньому, прагнучи віддати останнє нерозтрачене тепло. На блакитному і чистому небі ще майже немає хмар. Тільки вітер став більш холодним і різким, нагадуючи про те, що на дворі вже вересень місяць. Серед яскравої зелені помітні перші провісники осені: жовті і червоні листя. Скоро вони опаде з дерев і покриють собою все дороги і доріжки."

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)

for sentence in sentences:

 print(sentence)

 print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Все работает, проверьте отступы и синтаксис. Вот немного измененная программа - и ее вывод

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

text = "Сонце гріє ще майже по-літньому, прагнучи віддати останнє нерозтрачене тепло. На блакитному і чистому небі ще " \
       "майже немає хмар. Тільки вітер став більш холодним і різким, нагадуючи про те, що на дворі вже вересень " \
       "місяць. Серед яскравої зелені помітні перші провісники осені: жовті і червоні листя. Скоро вони опаде з дерев " \
       "і покриють собою все дороги і доріжки. "

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)

for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

Вывод:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\Serg\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
Сонце гріє ще майже по-літньому, прагнучи віддати останнє нерозтрачене тепло.
На блакитному і чистому небі ще майже немає хмар.
Тільки вітер став більш холодним і різким, нагадуючи про те, що на дворі вже вересень місяць.
Серед яскравої зелені помітні перші провісники осені: жовті і червоні листя.
Скоро вони опаде з дерев і покриють собою все дороги і доріжки.

Process finished with exit code 0
```